# Why does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS use a non-LTS kernel version?

Tags: kernel, lts, versions

I only recently became aware that LTS wasn't just an Ubuntu thing - there's LTS kernel versions too. Yet the kernel version used (3.13) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is not an LTS kernel version. Is it considered unimportant whether or not a kernel version is LTS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Ubuntu 14.04 LTS use linux kernel 3.13?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531253/why-ubuntu-14-04-lts-use-linux-kernel-3-13)

Comment: Essentially https://askubuntu.com/a/628587/158442's last para

Comment: @muru It is not really a dupe. I never met the `ckt` kernels explanation at AU. It is poorly documented probably because it is not for the users ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A short answer is: "It is an LTS kernel".

Mainline kernel developers didn't make it an LTS, but the Canonical Kernel Team did.

The 3.13 kernel is maintained as an LTS according to the mainline rules as `3.13-ckt`. Security and small hardware support patches are backported the same way as in mainline LTS kernels.

You can find the source here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/linux.git

Based on this kernel the Ubuntu debianized kernels are made.

The 3.13 Ubuntu kernel source is here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git

The main idea is that the Canonical Kernel Team extends support of mainline kernels when they are used in LTS Ubuntu releases.

When I send a kernel patch that is supposed to be backported to stable kernels, I add `Cc: stable@vger.kernel.org` to the commit message.

First it gets to the latest mainline kernels, then is backported to mainline LTS kernels and `ckt` kernels the same way.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, Pilot6. Seems strange that they wouldn't simply choose an LTS kernel and save themselves the added work but looking at 12.04 and 16.04, it seems 14.04 was a one-off exception.

Comment: The reason for that is to get a newer kernel for a new LTS release. They try to use LTS kernels when it is possible.

Comment: @Sam As you can see not only 3.13 is extended, but 3.19 and 4.2.

Comment: What actually got me thinking about this was installing Mint 18.2 (16.04.2-based) and getting kernel 4.8 (non-LTS) when 4.9 LTS had already been out for a while?

Comment: The 4.8 came from 16.10 as HWE. It was the latest at that time. If you know how it works, it is straight forward. 16.04.2 is not a new release.