# Will Ubuntu 18.04 be LTS or not?

Tags: kernel, lts, 18.04

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 Beta 1 on virtual machine and I was a little surprised when I checked the kernel version - it's `4.15.0-10-generic`.

Kernel 4.14 is LTS, but kernel 4.15 is non-LTS

I'm new to Linux, but I read that on kernel.org.

So, will Ubuntu 18.04 finally have kernel 4.14 or 4.15?

Comment: Short answer: Ubuntu 18.04 will have long time support, LTS.

Comment: See these for reference: [Why does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS use a non-LTS kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932859/why-does-ubuntu-14-04-lts-use-a-non-lts-kernel-version) & [Why Ubuntu 14.04 LTS use linux kernel 3.13?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531253/why-ubuntu-14-04-lts-use-linux-kernel-3-13)

Comment: So Ubuntu 18.04 final will have kernel 4.14 or 4.15?

Comment: Kernel 14.15 will probably be EOL when 18.04 ships but that won't stop Ubuntu from using it and sticking suffixes at the end to represent Kernel 4.14.35 or whatever the equivalent is. It confuses me too.