# Ubuntu 18 LTS Bionic Final Kernel Version

Tags: kernel

Will Ubuntu 18.04 systems eventually be upgraded to Kernel version 4.19 because that is a Longterm release?

According to: https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html
the current 4.15 kernel seems like it will not be supported.

Comment: Ubuntu kernels are supported by Canonical (ie. upstream security fixes are backported) so your Ubuntu kernel is supported as long as your are updated & using a supported release.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will have HWE kernels when they become available, so you have that option (it will use 18.10 kernels, 19.04, 19.10 until finally landing on 20.04 like 16.04, 14.04 before it with HWE enabled), but HWE kernels become available on 18.04.2's release  (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: See these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932859/why-does-ubuntu-14-04-lts-use-a-non-lts-kernel-version and https://askubuntu.com/questions/531253/why-ubuntu-14-04-lts-use-linux-kernel-3-13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu kernels are supported by Canonical (ie. upstream security fixes are backported to the Ubuntu LTS kernels) so your Ubuntu kernel is supported as long as your are updated & using a supported release.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will have HWE kernels when they become available, so you will soon have that option (it will use 18.10 kernels, 19.04, 19.10 until finally landing on 20.04 like 16.04, 14.04 before it with HWE enabled), but HWE kernels become available on 18.04.2's release. They provide later features (usually wanted for very recent hardware) but do not provide better security (given they've been less tested in production, and security-patches are backported to more stable-kernels) but we do have the choice.

refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for more information.